# How to calculate 10% discounted value when user types an amount in form in yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I have two textboxes in my Yii2 Form - mrp,rate. What I want is when user types an amount in mrp, 10% discounted value will be populated in rate. Say user types 100 in mrp, the value populated in rate will be 90. And this will show till 2 places after decimal i.e. 90.00.
The code I have is as following -

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\batchno\models\Productbatch */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="productbatch-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'batchno')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'mfgdate')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'expdate')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'mrp')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'rate')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>

 <?php
    $ this->RegisterJs ( "

    $('#Productbatch-mrp').keyup(function(){ 
                     var total = this.value;
                     var percent = 10;
                     var discount_value = (total / 100) * percent;
                    $('#Productbatch-rate').val(discount_value);    
                 });
                });

    " ,  View :: POS_END);

  ?>
```

Comment: what is your $model name?

Comment: My model name is "Productbatch"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `Html::getInputId($model, 'mrp')` instead of `Productbatch-mrp` in selector of jquery code. Hope its help you.

```
<?php
    $this->RegisterJs ( "
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#".Html::getInputId($model, 'mrp')."').keyup(function(){ 
                     var total = this.value;
                     var percent = 10;
                     var discount_value = (total * percent) / 100 ;
                     var rate = total - discount_value;
                    $('#".Html::getInputId($model, 'rate')."').val(rate);    
                 });
    });

    ", View::POS_END);
  ?>
```

Comment: Class 'View' not found

Comment: put this line of code on top of your file `use yii\web\View;`

Comment: The formula is not exactly what I want. But I've got how to do it. Many many Thanks to GATIMG and Shahzad.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion, separate javascript and _form.php, use assets.

In jour _form.php file get to use asset class:

```
use frontend\assets\XyzAsset;
XyzAsset::register($this);
```

Create in frontend/assets file XyzAsset.php :

```
class XyzAsset extends AssetBundle {

    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/MyJavaScriptFile.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

}
```

Then, in frontend/web create directory js and file MyJavaScriptFile.js
In MyJavaScriptFile.js create function:

```
function discount() {    
    document.getElementById("abc-mrp").onblur=function(e) {
        var amount = document.getElementById("abc-mrp").value;
        document.getElementById("abc-rate").value = amount - (amount *  10 / 100).toFixed(2);
    }    
}
discount();
```

Asset documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html